# Accesing a static ArrayList from another class in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

The ArrayList needs to be set to static. I created a getter method in the main class (CityMenuCreate).In the second class, I do call the method and when I try to create a **for** function, it doesn't recognize the list.

The method I created in the first class (CityMenuCreate)

```
public static ArrayList getCityList() {
    return cityList;
}
```

The part of code I'm trying to call the method in the second class

```
CityMenuCreate.getCityList();
for(int i=0; i< **cityList.size();** i++) {
            
}
```

It gives me an error in the **cityList.size();**. Is there a syntax problem in the for function?

Comment: don't use static access - it's nearly always the wrong approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of `CityMenuCreate.getCityList()`. You either need to save it to a local variable:

```java
List cityList = CityMenuCreate.getCityList();
for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
    // code
}
```

Or just use it directly from that method:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < CityMenuCreate.getCityList().size(); i++) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above example, you've declared your `getCityList()` method as static, not your Arraylist. Hence you cannot access your Arraylist in a static way. You either declare your Arraylist static or in your for loop you call the method like so:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < CityMenuCreate.getCityList().size(); i++) {
     //Your code goes here
 }
```